# Log of loaded cshtml view files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging

We have some obsolete views in our MVC 4 web project. I would like to create some statistic on how often are view files accessed, if at all. If some files are not accessed in a long time, it's possible they are obsolete.

Is it possible to get this information from IIS or windows logs?

Comment: Maybe just put an IIS redirect on those pages, redirect to a action which logs browser.request referrer, and show a "this page has moved" view? This way, you know if they are being accessed, you know where the request are coming from, and you provide some sort of explanation for why this page no longer exists, or shouldnt be accessed.

Comment: Not retrospective - but add a simple action filter to your request pipeline and log each action to find out which ones are in use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter context before and after action finished execution

to log which view is accesss you can use following example

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
   string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName
   .....
   base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

form the controller and actionname you can maintain your view log's

i hope it help's you..

Comment: But actions and views do not map 1 to 1. There are partial views without actions

Comment: You can map partialview also @MiroslavZadravec.. do one thing put this code in base controller and inherit to every controller then put breakpoint in this method.debug your application and call partial view you.